# How can I get all transactions into and out of a bitcoin address in JSON format?

Tags: address, blockchain.info, api

For example if I use https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/$bitcoin_address,  it shows only the first 100 txs. How can I get all transactions if the number of txs is greater than 100?

Answer (score 1):

Their API documentation tells you:

> https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/$bitcoin_address
> Address can be base58 or hash160
> Optional limit parameter to show n transactions e.g. &limit=50 (Default: 50, Max: 50)
> Optional offset parameter to skip the first n transactions e.g. &offset=100 (Page 2 for limit 50)

So use the offset parameter and repeat until all data retrieved.